# Unable to mock a dispatch function to use in test case in React to track click event been fired from the component

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I was trying to write a test case to mock a dispatch. Basically there is a component where a dispatch function is called from within a eventhandler. So I wanted to check whether that button is getting clicked. But unable to do so.

-----Lgin.test.ts----

```
import {render,screen, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'
import Login from './Login';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import Thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import * as redux from "react-redux";
it(" Test button click", async()=>{
     const initialState = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    isSubmit: false
};
const mockStore = configureStore([Thunk]);
    let store = mockStore(initialState); 

    const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch'); 
    
  
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Login />
        </Provider>
        );  

    const rObj = screen.getByTestId("lginsbmit");         
    fireEvent.click(rObj);
    
    expect(useDispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    
    useDispatchSpy.mockClear();

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey guys I made these changes and it worked for me, hope this helps other people too:

```
it(" RTL test to check button clicked i.e internally track dispatch function clicked", async()=>{

    let store = mockStore(initialState); 

    const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch'); 
    const mockDispatchFn = jest.fn()        
    useDispatchSpy.mockReturnValue(mockDispatchFn);
  
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Login />
        </Provider>
        );  

    const rObj = screen.getByTestId("lginsbmit");        
    fireEvent.click(rObj);
    
    expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    //teardown
    useDispatchSpy.mockClear();

})
```

Comment: I am getting this error - Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given